# How to index collection by using composite key

Tags: c#, performance, collections, concurrency, composite-index

I have this class

```
public class Item
{
    public int UniqueKey;
    public int Key1;
    public int Key2;
    public int Key3;
    public int Key4;
    public string Value;
}
```

and the collection `IEnumerable<Item>`

I want to create indexes on items of this collection by **Key1**, or by **Key2**, or composite one (**Key1 and Key4**). The number of items in collection is about 10 000 or more. The main goal is performance. Multiple callers can have many read / one write access. Returned collections should be guarded (protected from external modification). Could somebody explain any solution, pattern, what collection classes I have to use to implement.

I have rejected the variant of using database table's indexes, because of some reasons (performance and so on).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two mappings: one for the store and one as a lookup table to the primary key. As all updates use the primary key which should be fixed, you can use lock stripping to allow concurrent writes. In this form a writer must acquire a lock (primaryKey mod # locks) so that an updates/removes do not race for an entry. And, of course, reads don't need locking if the backing dictionaries are concurrent.

You can see a Java [version](http://code.google.com/p/concurrentlinkedhashmap/wiki/IndexableCache) of this idea which was hidden behind a caching facade to provide a nice API.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to return a collection indexed by a property:

```
var key1 = from i in Items 
           group i by i.Key1 into g
           select g;

var key2 = from i in Items
           group i by i.Key2 into g
           select g;
...
```

Since you have a small, deterministic list of keys, you could implement a class that exposes the groups for read as `IEnumerable` or `List` properties.  Add a single method for adding items to the collection (no need for separate methods since they'll get grouped for reading based on their value.)  Use the `lock` keyword in your Add method to protect the item collections while adding.

Comment: lock? why not ReaderWriterLockSlim? :)

Comment: and why only on Add (what about Get?)

Comment: @igor: Use the grouped properties for Get.  As for your locking mechanism, use whatever you think will work best ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could group the items using an anonymous type and create a dictionary with the groups:

```
var grouped = items.GroupBy(item => new { item.Key1, item.Key4 })
                   .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
```

However, anonymous types can only be used for local variables (or generic method parameters), so if you're going to store the dictionary for later reuse, you will need a non-anonymous type. So you can either create types for each possible key combination, or use the `Tuple` class :

```
Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, Item> grouped =
              items.GroupBy(item => Tuple.Create(item.Key1, item.Key2))
                   .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
```